# Are Hollows defeated by humans who are not Quincies considered as destroyed or "purified"?

Tags: bleach

If I remember correctly, Shinigami are "purifying" Hollows with Zanpakuto, cleansing souls and sending them to Soul Society (not counting cases when souls are going to Hell). And regarding Quincy, it was said that the main conflict between Quincies and Shinigami was that, unlike Shinigami, Quincies were destroying souls when killing Hollows, which was bad for balance.

In series, it was shown numerous times that Hollows can also be defeated by humans having certain abilities, for example, Yasutora Sado, Orihime Inoue, Hanakari Jinta, etc. So, what happens with Hollow soul in this case? Is it exorcised, or destroyed, just like by Quincy hand?

Comment: just going off the animations in the anime when Chad, Orihime and the Non-Soul Reapers of the Urahara Shoop kill a Hollow the Hollow vanishes the same way it does when a Soul Reaper kill it (from the bottom up). when we see a Quincy kill one there is a slightly different animation in which the Hollow vanishes (outward from where the last Arrow hit and there's a small light in the center plus white particles). could be an indication

Comment: I still consider that only way to purify a soul is by a zanpakto. Even kidou would destroy a soul, the same way as a Quincy. Only reason why Shinigami would use zanpakto instead of a cool ranged laser attack to destroy a hollow.

Comment: I believe they are also "purified" when killed by humans with abilities.

Answer (score 1):

If killed by a Soul Reaper they go to Soul Society if they were actually good, so only the bad ones go to Hell. Quincy destroy them completely. Humans just kill them and send them to Hell. Only Soul Reapers purify them.

---

Not a source, but I watched all episodes of Bleach and finished the manga. At one point they are talking about how Chad's or Orihime's powers are special. Chad said something about his spiritual pressure doing something when he went to Hueco Mundo, and Hachigan was a Soul Reaper/Vizard with Orihime's power.

Captain Kurotsuchi also said it when he realized the Quincy were invading.

Comment: Is there any source to back-up your answer?

Comment: All things considered, this answer is correct.  Just adding the episode information would make is verifiable, and an edit for grammar would make it good.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually answered in one of the episodes.
There needs to be a balance between people dying and souls going into Soul Society and Quincy's were disrupting that balance by erasing the souls altogether instead of cleansing them.
This disruption took such proportions that soul reapers and quincy's went to war.
It seems to follow that, since shinigami are apparantly the only ones actually sending the soul somewhere, all other forms of combating Hollows will result in the destruction of the soul, rather than the relocation of it.

I do not have an episode number but I do have a backup source:

http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Quincy

See chapter 3.2 Fall of the Quincy for more info.

Answer (score 0):

They would be destroyed, chad is closer to a hollows, and a soul reapers zanpaktou is meant to purify/condemn hollows.  Ex.  Other groups, either absorb the people, and the world around them in soul society, are Quincy, or just have a different specification.  They never mention ichigos friends purifying them, as far as I am aware, so it's either a plot hole, or they die.  Since, in usual cases, they have soul reaper assigned to the area, it would be reasonable to liken them to a Quincy.